# Nvidia GPU vs CPU benchmark: what kind of cpu they refer to?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I found that Nvidia GPU often has 10x improvement in speed than CPU. However, I did know what CPU they compare to. For example, for Tesla K80 (see below link) comparison, they did not specify the CPU.

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/tesla-k80/

Do you know what kind of CPU they usually use for benchmark (e.g., Intel Core i7)?

Answer (score 0):

My friend, the test specifications are literally right underneath the graph.

"CPU Server: Dual Socket E5-2698v3@2.3GHz 3.6GHz Turbo (Haswell EP) HT off"

"GPU Server: Dual Socket E5-2698v3@2.3GHz 3.6GHz Turbo (Haswell EP) HT off, Dual K20/K80 GPU Boost enabled"